# Not able to call .asmx web-service from Ajax in .net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, web-services, webmethod

I have an existing .net solution which uses windows authentication. Now i added another project for Web-service in existing solution and created a .asmx service there. Through ajax i am trying to call that web-service as below

Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "HelloService/HelloData.asmx/HelloWorld",
    data: "{parameterList:" + JSON.stringify(model) + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function (jsondata) {
      alert(jsondata);
    }, error: function (x, e) {
      alert("Error")          
    }
});
```

and here is my .asmx service

```
namespace HelloService
{
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HelloData
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string parameterList)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
}
```

In the above code, i am getting error as `No web service found at: /HelloService/HelloData.asmx.` in "Global.asax.cs" file in "Application_error" method. What's wrong here and what needs to be done?

Comment: Can I ask why you're creating a new ASMX service in 2019? Why aren't you using [Web API](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/apis) instead?

Comment: Your JavaScript "data: "{parameterList:" + JSON.stringify(model) + "}" is wrong it should be  data:  '{parameterList: "' + JSON.stringify(model) + '"}'  this.
and remove  async: true, it will excute the next statement even if the responce not came .

Answer (score 0):

It is already shown in the code, in order to call ASMX web service from Javascript, you need to add the `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService` attribute.

You can simply uncomment the line, so your code will be like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for HelloData
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class HelloData : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld(string parameterList)
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

Notice that the `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService` attribute is now applied.